# Android Coin-Toss Simulator Lagging

Tags: android, performance, random

Ok I am new to android programming but i have created an app as follows.

```
package com.michaelpeerman.probability;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class ProbabilityActivity extends Activity
{
  private EditText number;
  private Button submit;

  public void flipcoin(int numberint)
  {
    TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    int heads = 0;
    int tails = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < numberint; j++)
    {
      int i = 1 + new Random().nextInt(2);
      if (i == 1)
        heads++;
      if (i == 2)
        tails++;
      result.setText("heads : " + heads + "\ntails : " + tails);
    }
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    submit = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.submit));
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View paramView)
      {
        number = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.number));
        int numberint = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
        flipcoin(numberint);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

But this runs incredibly slow compared to

```
package com.michaelpeerman.probability;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class ProbabilityActivity extends Activity
{


  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


        TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        int heads = 0;
        int tails = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 50000; j++)
        {
          int i = 1 + new Random().nextInt(2);
          if (i == 1)
            heads++;
          if (i == 2)
            tails++;
          result.setText("heads : " + heads + "\ntails : " + tails);

  }
}
```

I do not understand why this is. They are both using the same code except the first one lets you enter in a number and press submit before running the loop.
Shouldnt they be the same speed? What can I do to speed it up?

Comment: Few tips, Don't create a `new Random()` inside the loop. Create it once.

Comment: Is the looped action slower? Or is the overall app slower?

Comment: I think I found the problem. The problem was i was having it set the text in the loop. I changed it so that it now sets it outside of the loop.

Comment: How do I create a random outside of the loop for the loop to use?

Answer (score 0):

First of all is the app lagging for any input you give or is it only for specific values.The only extra computation that is being done is the conversion from string to int which should not cause it to lag. The problem may exist due to some problem with the memory allocations or exceptions not caught. Can you post the logs if you are running this on a emulator.